# Postgis / Geodjango: Cannot determine PostGIS version for database

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I'm attempting to launch a GeoDjango app. I've installed Postgres & PostGIS using brew on Lion. I created a database using template_postgis: `createdb -T template_postgis test`.

When I run `python manage.py syncdb`, I get the following error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot determine
>   PostGIS version for database "test". GeoDjango requires at least
>   PostGIS version 1.3. Was the database created from a spatial database
>   template?

How can I track down the source of the error? I've checked that the user & pass in the config have access to the database etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As a first debugging step: try to check the postgis template version manually, e.g. on the command-line connect to your database with `psql test`, and query with `select postgis_lib_version();`. This function should be defined in template_postgis and return some number. Example output:

```
$ psql test
psql (9.0.4)
Type "help" for help.

test=# select postgis_lib_version();

 postgis_lib_version
---------------------
 1.5.2
(1 row)
```

If an error occurs, you know the error is in the database.

Comment: Hi Sandeep, what does your output state?

Comment: sorry..i got it working..i had to follow https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/postgis/#post-installation

Comment: just about: `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` running in shell of your db

Comment: This is same error when Postgres is not running. So just run Postgres and it will work.

Answer (score 40):

Just add in your settings.py your right version of postgis :

> POSTGIS_VERSION = (2, 0, 3)

Comment: That solves it. I'd still like to understand why geodjango can't work it out by itself though...

Answer (score 10):

The solution for me was to run the following in the postgres terminal:

```
psql database_name

database_name=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

---

If you get `ERROR:  relation "spatial_ref_sys" already exists`, run the following before `CREATE EXTENSION postgis`:

```
 drop table spatial_ref_sys;
 drop table geometry_columns;
```

Answer (score 3):

And in case the previous select returns an error, it may be that one particular version of PostGIS was installed on that database, that you updated Postgres.app to a newer version, that bundles a newer version of PostGIS. For example, after the recent update from Postgis 2.0 to 2.1

In that case, you can make a migration after copying back some libraries, like described in [this ticket](https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/87)

Answer (score 2):

if you are using `django_debug_toolbar` try to delete it or comment out `debug_toolbar/utils/tracking/db.py` line 152 as suggested on https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/issues/442