# Geometry Doesn't exist in GEODJANGO

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I have installed all the dependies of Geodjango! Now i am following its tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/ -- Problem: command python manage.py syncdb generates error at `mpoly geometry(multipolygon 4326) not null that geometry does not exist`

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class WorldBorders(models.Model):
    # Regular Django fields corresponding to the attributes in the
    # world borders shapefile.
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    area = models.IntegerField()
    pop2005 = models.IntegerField('Population 2005')
    fips = models.CharField('FIPS Code', max_length=2)
    iso2 = models.CharField('2 Digit ISO', max_length=2)
    iso3 = models.CharField('3 Digit ISO', max_length=3)
    un = models.IntegerField('United Nations Code')
    region = models.IntegerField('Region Code')
    subregion = models.IntegerField('Sub-Region Code')
    lon = models.FloatField()
    lat = models.FloatField()

    # GeoDjango-specific: a geometry field (MultiPolygonField), and
    # overriding the default manager with a GeoManager instance.
    mpoly = models.MultiPolygonField() //ERROR HERE
```

How to solve this error?

**UPDATE:**

`python manage.py sqlall world` generates following output:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "world_worldborders" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    "area" integer NOT NULL,
    "pop2005" integer NOT NULL,
    "fips" varchar(2) NOT NULL,
    "iso2" varchar(2) NOT NULL,
    "iso3" varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    "un" integer NOT NULL,
    "region" integer NOT NULL,
    "subregion" integer NOT NULL,
    "lon" double precision NOT NULL,
    "lat" double precision NOT NULL,
    "mpoly" geometry(MULTIPOLYGON,4326) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE INDEX "world_worldborders_mpoly_id" ON "world_worldborders" USING GIST ( "mpoly" );

COMMIT;
```

and `python manage.py syncdb` generates: `Program Error Geometry Doesn't exist` :

`root@cvp-linux:~/geodjango# python manage.py syncdb
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Creating table django_admin_log
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table world_worldborders
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 92, in handle_noargs
    syncdb.Command().execute(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 107, in handle_noargs
    cursor.execute(statement)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 51, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: type "geometry" does not exist
LINE 14:     "mpoly" geometry(MULTIPOLYGON,4326) NOT NULL`

Comment: Did you solve it? would you plz share with us. Thx

Answer (score 5):

A couple of things to check for:

- You've run `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`
- The GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH is set in your project's settings.py file

This second point gave me some trouble, though it was the first that did the trick finally.  I'm running this on Cygwin 64 bit, so there's a bit of extra work to do to make it work.  If you're not running in the Cygwin environment, most likely the file you're looking for is libgeos_c.so; I needed to point it to cyggeos_c-1.dll (still running on Windows, so the .dll extension is what I needed to find).

I was positive that I had run the CREATE EXTENSION command already, but I may not have run it in the Cygwin environment. Or I had tried, but had failed to remember that I have a nightmare of a configuration such that the postgres server is not running on localhost, so I was avoiding psql.  Such is my own brand of thickness.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed ticket,

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21547

Updated [GeoDjango](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/GeoDjango) tutorial with PostGIS 2 output

Comment: Before posting question here i read this but I don't understand that ticket. can you please explain the steps to solve this problem?

Comment: Try this `python manage.py sqlall world` and post the output in your question

Comment: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot determine PostGIS version for database "geodjango". GeoDjango requires at least PostGIS version 1.3. Was the database created from a spatial database template?` @dhana
`

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491798/postgis-geodjango-cannot-determine-postgis-version-for-database

Comment: check the minimum requirements https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#spatial-database

Comment: add this `GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = '/home/bob/local/lib/libgeos_c.so'` in your settings.py file  here refrence link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/#can-t-find-geos-library

Comment: No @dhana It's again generating program error : `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: type "geometry" does not exist
LINE 14:     "mpoly" geometry(MULTIPOLYGON,4326) NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that the commands:

```
-- Enable PostGIS (includes raster)
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
-- Enable Topology
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
-- fuzzy matching needed for Tiger
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
-- Enable US Tiger Geocoder
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_tiger_geocoder;
```

shoudl be run in context of certain database, so you need to connect to `your_db` first:

```
\connect your_db
```

and then run above!

Answer (score 0):

try adding

`objects = models.GeoManager()`

after mpoly in your models.py

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to add a description *how* this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using postgis with your table/model in the public schema:

`CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`

Assuming you created another schema for your table/model, em settings.py add options:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME,public'
        },
        'NAME': 'DATABASE_NAME',
        'USER': 'DATABASE_USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'DATABASE_PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'DATABASE_HOST',
        'PORT': 'DATABASE_PORT',
    }
}
```